# jQuery check if two passwords match

Tags: jquery

So I'm busy on this system, which includes a registration for users. Now I need jQuery to check if the password and the password confirmation are matching. This is what I've come up with:

```js
$("#pass2").keypress(function() {
  if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val()) {
    $(".nosamepass").fadeIn('slow');
    $("#choosepass > input").css("border", "5px solid #ff0033");
  } else {
    $(".nosamepass").fadeOut('slow');
    $("#choosepass > input").css("border", "5px solid #232323");
  }
});
```

```css
.nosamepass {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="choosePass">
  <h1>{{goodgoing}}<span id="name2"></span></h1>
  <h2>{{choosepassword}}</h2>
  <h3>{{almostthere}}</h3>

  <input name="pass1" id="pass1" type="password" class="password" placeholder="{{password}}">
  <input name="pass2" id="pass2" type="password" class="password" placeholder="{{password2}}">

  <div class="nosamepass">TEST</div>
  <button id="regme" disabled="disabled">{{finishregister}} ></button>
</div>
```

But for some reason, this doesn't work. What happens is that when I type 2 identical passwords, it shows the `.nosamepass`. When the passwords are different, it also shows. Also it won't go away when I first mismatch them, and then correct it.

The `.nosamepass` is hidden through an external CSS file.

How to solve this?

**EDIT**

I just found out, that when I put 'a' in both input fields, it says that they aren't alike. When I put in a second character in `#pass2` (the second input field), then it says they they're alike. But they aren't.

Comment: @Joost: UX, presumably

Comment: @Joost This is the only way i know to do this without submitting a form and refreshing the page...

Comment: Good debugging practice is to throw an alert() where you aren't going.

Comment: I don't know what version of jQuery you're running, but I just chose 2.2.1 in order to insert a code snippet.  It's easy for you to change if that's wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TJ Crowder already gave the correct explanation, but I think it makes more sense to change your listener to 'keyup'

```js
$("#pass2").keyup(function() {
  if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val()) {
    $(".nosamepass").fadeIn('slow');
    $("#choosepass > input").css("border", "5px solid #ff0033");
  } else {
    $(".nosamepass").fadeOut('slow');
    $("#choosepass > input").css("border", "5px solid #232323");
  }
});
```

```css
.nosamepass {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="choosePass">
  <input name="pass1" id="pass1" type="password" class="password" placeholder="{{password}}">
  <input name="pass2" id="pass2" type="password" class="password" placeholder="{{password2}}">

  <div class="nosamepass">Passwords Don't Match</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when `keypress` runs, the value of the `input` hasn't been updated yet (because you might prevent the default action, which is updating the value of the input).

You can use the `setTimeout(..., 0)` trick to call your code after the event completes:

```js
$("#pass2").keypress(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val()) {
      $(".nosamepass").fadeIn('slow');
      $("#choosepass > input").css("border", "5px solid #ff0033");
    } else {
      $(".nosamepass").fadeOut('slow');
      $("#choosepass > input").css("border", "5px solid #232323");
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<div id="choosePass">
  <h1>{{goodgoing}}<span id="name2"></span></h1>
  <h2>{{choosepassword}}</h2>
  <h3>{{almostthere}}</h3>
  <input name="pass1" id="pass1" type="password" class="password" placeholder="{{password}}">
  <input name="pass2" id="pass2" type="password" class="password" placeholder="{{password2}}">
  <div class="nosamepass">TEST</div>
  <button id="regme" disabled="disabled">{{finishregister}} ></button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happens now, is that when i test, by typing 'a' into both fields it works. When i type another a, in the second field, it works. Now, when I take away the second 'a' in the second field, its not working, since the `.nosamepass` stays there.